# Uniqueness of simple unsigned integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

This is a *uniqueness problem* of the *Simple unsigned integral* that I'm struggling with.

> A function $f$ is called *simple unsigned function* if it can be written as
>   $$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^k c_i 1_{E_i}(x)$$
>   for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $c_i \in [0,+\infty] ~\forall~ i=1(1)k~$ where $E_i$'s are *Lebesgue measurable sets*.
>
> The *simple unsigned integral* of the function $f$ is defined as
>   $$Simp \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)dx:=\sum_{i=1}^k c_im(E_i)$$
>   where $m(\cdot)$ denotes the *Lebesgue measure*.

The problem is to show that the *simple unsigned integral* $f \to Simp \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)dx$ is the only map from the space **Simp**$^+(\mathbb{R}^d)$ to $[0,+\infty]$ that obeys all the following properties:

> $(i)$ (*Unsigned linearity*) Let $\alpha, \beta \in [0, +\infty]$.  $$Simp \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\{\alpha f(x)+\beta g(x)\}dx=\alpha \times Simp \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)dx+\beta \times Simp \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}g(x)dx$$
>
> $(ii)$ (*Finiteness*) $Simp \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)dx < +\infty$ *iff* $f$ is finite *a.e.* and the *support* of $f$ is finite.
>
> $(iii)$ (*Vanishing*) $Simp \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)dx = 0$ *iff* $f=0$ *a.e.*
>
> $(iv)$ (*Equivalence*) $f=g$ *a.e.* $\implies$ $Simp \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)dx=Simp \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}g(x)dx$
>
> $(v)$ (*Monotonicity*) $f \leq g$ *a.e.* $\implies$ $Simp \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)dx \leq Simp \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}g(x)dx$
>
> $(vi)$ (*Compatibility with Lebesgue measure*) For any *Lebesgue measurable set* $E$, $$Simp \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}1_E(x)dx=m(E)$$

I'm defining an arbitrary functional $M:$ **Simp**$^+(\mathbb{R}^d) \to [0,+\infty]$ that follows the properties and I do realize that I have to show the that $$M(f)=k \times Simp \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)dx$$ using the properties $(i)-(v)$ and then to use property $(vi)$ (*Compatibility with Lebesgue measure*) to get the *normalizing constant* $k=1$. But I'm not being able to penetrate the first part. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For properties (ii) through (vi) you can assume that $f$ is a characteristic function of a measurable set, because property (i) shows that $M$ is completely determined by these. However, before you even start, don't you need to show that $\operatorname{Simp}$ is well-defined? In general a simple function may have many representations of the form $\sum_{i=1}^{k}c_i 1_{E_i}(x)$ (unless the $c_i$'s are assumed to be distinct and nonzero).

Comment: @Bungo: Actually the fact that **Simp** is *well-defined* was the previous problem which I've already done. So yes, I need to show that but didn't bother in this problem as I just did it in the previous one. But I don't get how $M$ gets completely determined by these properties!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $M : \mathbf{Simp}^+(\mathbb R^d) \to [0,\infty]$ is a map satisfying (i) and (vi).

Let $f \in \mathbf{Simp}^+(\mathbb R^d)$, say $f = \sum_{i=1}^{k}c_i 1_{E_i}$.

By (i), $M(f) = \sum_{i=1}^{k}c_i M(1_{E_i})$.

By (vi), $M(1_{E_i}) = m(E_i)$.

Therefore,
$$M(f) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} c_i m(E_i) = \operatorname{Simp}\int_{\mathbb R^d}f(x)\ dx$$

So, we only need properties (i) and (vi) to establish uniqueness. Now you just need to show that the simple unsigned integral does indeed satisfy (ii) through (v).